# Setters, why won't this work?

Tags: java, setter

I've been toying for hours, changing static, private, public etcetera :) But it still won't work. If I change static at one place, I get an error at another place etc.

I have a class called person. I've used NON-static Setters because the `Person()` constructor is also non-static.

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String lastname;
    private String nickname; 

    Person() {
        this.name = ""; 
        this.lastname = ""; 
        this.nickname = "";  
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name; 
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;  
    }

    public void setNickname(String nickname) {
        this.nickname = nickname; 
    }
}
```

Then I have a file with my main method, and different methods for interacting with the user.This method is also static because it calls that methods that take the userInput which is using the `Scanner` class.

```
public class Interaction {
    public static void takeName() {
        String name; 
        String lastname;
        String nickname;  

        System.out.println("What is your firstname:");
        name = userInput(); // calls method with Scanner class
        System.out.println("What is your lastname:");
        lastname = userInput(); // calls method with Scanner class
        System.out.println("What is your nickname:");
        nickname = userInput(); 

        person.setName(name);
        person.setLastname(lastname); 
        person.setNickname(nickname); 
    }
//editor: missing closing bracket
```

What I've tried:

- I've tried to dat `Person.person.setname(name);`
- Declare the String in the public class `Interaction`, and then pass the String using this.name and call the method from the public class `Interaction`
- tried to change static, private etc. etc.
- Delete the constructor class `Person(`) in `Person` class.

What am I missing here?

EDIT: I'VE ADDED SOME MORE INFO as you requested :)

My new `Person` object will be declared if it passes an if statement.

IF there is a place available then a new person will be created and added to this place.

```
public class Theater {
    void reservationSystem () {
        if (availability > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < freespaces.length; i++) {
                if (freespaces[i].person == null) {
                    freespaces[i].person = new Person(); 
                    break; 
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No tickets for you today :) ");
        }
    }
//editor: missing closing bracket
```

So my way of thinking is:

- I fill a constructor with the data from the `Userinput()` using the `Scanner` class;
- and THEN I create the new `Person` object so it has that data!
- When I create a new `Person` in the reservation system, then the data in the constructor will be filled with data AGAIN but now with new data :)

If you need any more information please let me know :)

Comment: First, why is `Public` capitalised; is that a typo? Second, where do you declare your `person` variable?

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: How are you testing that setters are not working? Also, what is the code written in userInput() ?

Comment: can you show me your main method?

Comment: Please post the code of userInput() too! And how on Earth could a **constructor** be **static**?

Comment: This does no work : `Person.person.setname(name);` Where as this will : `Person person = new Person(); person.setname("john");`

Comment: Because this is not valid syntax: `Person.person.setname(name);` What this would mean is: 1. get class named `Person` 2. get **static field** named `person` 3. find and invoke **instance methid** `setname` with argument `name`

Comment: First you have to create a Person object and then you have to set the name

Comment: Provide a complete example that can be copied, pasted, compiled and executed.

Comment: What does "it still won't work" mean? What's the compile/runtime error you get?

Comment: Do a little homework before you start coding! There is a huge number of books and the Web is full of examples that will get you started.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to note is that your `Person` constructor is a little useless, you can rewrite `Person` as such:

```
public class Person {

    private String name = "";
    private String lastname = "";
    private String nickname = "";

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public void setNickname(String nickname) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }
}
```

Now onto your `Interaction` `class`. This needs to by `public` rather than `Public` but I assume that's a typo.

You need to have an `instance` of `Person` to call your setters on as they are `instance` methods. You need to somewhere call `new Person()`.

The easiest way of writing your `takeName()` method is by creating a `Person` *in the method* and `return`ing the instance:

```
public class Interaction {

    public static Person takeName() {
        final Person person = new Person();
        System.out.println("What is your firstname:");
        person.setName(userInput());
        System.out.println("What is your lastname:");
        person.setLastname(userInput());
        System.out.println("What is your nickname:");
        person.setNickname(userInput());
        return person;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your 'takeName()` function should update a **single instance** of the Person class.

One approach is to create the `Person` externally and pass it to the function:

```
Public class Interaction {
    public static void takeName(Person person) {
      String name; 
      String lastname;
      String nickname;  

      System.out.println("What is your firstname:");
      name = userInput(); // calls method with Scanner class
      System.out.println("What is your lastname:");
      lastname = userInput(); // calls method with Scanner class
      System.out.println("What is your nickname:");
      nickname = userInput(); 

      person.setName(name);
      person.setLastname(lastname); 
      person.setNickname(nickname); 
  }
}
```

But I think it would be more intuitive to create the person instance inside the function and return it:

```
Public class Interaction {
    public static Person takeName() {
      String name; 
      String lastname;
      String nickname;  

      Person person = new Person();

      System.out.println("What is your firstname:");
      name = userInput(); // calls method with Scanner class
      System.out.println("What is your lastname:");
      lastname = userInput(); // calls method with Scanner class
      System.out.println("What is your nickname:");
      nickname = userInput(); 


      person.setName(name);
      person.setLastname(lastname); 
      person.setNickname(nickname); 

      return person;
  }
}
```

Comment: I disagree: the first implementation allows for using **descendant classes** of Person too - while the second one is tied to that implementation...

Comment: both have pros and conns, depending on what the original asker is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is not valid syntax: `Person.person.setname(name);`

What this would mean in this context is:

1. get class named `Person`
2. get **static field** of `Person` class named `person`
3. find and invoke **instance methid** `setname` with argument `name`

But your `Person` class - *appropriately* - does not have a static field named person...

The root cause of your issues is most likely not being entirely familiar with the concept of classes, instances, and in connection, the meaning of static and instance members and methods...

- **Static** always means the referenced part is connected with the **class**.
- Whereas an **instance variable or method** (e.g. everything non-static)  is connected to the **instances** of said classes.